# How to take Docker configuration back up?

Tags: rhel, docker

I want to upgrade the Docker version on RHEL 7.9 at my workplace. My company operates behind a proxy, and there may be configurations related to it that I'm unaware of.

What are the necessary configuration files or folders that I should back up before proceeding with the Docker upgrade?

Comment: "and there may be configurations related to it..." you mean you don't know for sure if such configuration exists? That's going to make it hard to identify problems after the upgrade. Generally, configuration for the Docker daemon lives in `/etc/docker`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, it is a legacy system and doesn't have any documentation related to what has been configured for Docker setup on that. So trying to figure out.